# What is the point of adding extra divs?

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between these two? What difference does it make if we put another div inside the first div?

```
<div class="blah">
    <div class="blahInner>
        <img src="pony.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blah">
    <img src="pony.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't upvote anything. I just joined github I'm still figuring everything out. I'll upvote you then.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple divs allow you to customise your HTML with different effects based on  properties assigned to different CSS attributes. Additionally, the use of multiple divs allow you to add different kinds of CSS and, jS to elements of your HTML page. Rather than have all your CSS within one selector, you can then spread it across multiple divs which allows you or someone else working on your code to easily make sense of it.

You may also want to pair different sets of styling for different parts of the webpage, and having multiple divs will enable you to easily call the same divs and form combinations of the attributes from different selectors. Ultimately, you could just use them as follows,

```
<div class="art" id="dart">
Text
</div>
```

OR with multiple divs as shown below.

```css
.dart {
  color: white;
}

#art {
  background-color: #ADFF2F;
  width: 115px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="art">
  <div class="dart">
    I am dummy text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there is no difference and is therefore useless unless you use it in your linked CSS or JavaScript.

The difference is that there is another `<div>` element for other web languages like CSS or JavaScript to act upon.

It gives the other languages a chance to add special positioning, animations, and styles to the containing `<div>` element.

I hope this answer was informative.

Let me know if you have any complaints.

Comment: Would the CSS and Javascript affect the first div or the one inside of it? Let's say I want to move the pony image to a specific place and have it be responsive, do I manipulate the "blah" class, the "blah-inner" or the image itself?

Comment: That depends.  You would probably have to target each element separately.  Since they are each nested inside the other they will usually work together.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, extra `div` acts as a sub-category.

Extending to your example, lest's say there are 2 sub classes (`blahInner1` & `blahInner2`) within the class `blah`. We can easily manipulate font of `blahInner2` only.

```html
<div class="blah">
    <div class="blahInner1">
        <img src="pony.jpg">
        This is 1st caption.
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="blahInner2">
        <img src="pony.jpg">
        This is 2nd caption.
    </div>
</div>

<style>.blahInner2{color: red;}</style>
```